# AWS Athena - Add new column when using CREATE AS SELECT

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I want to create a new table based on an existing table, but with some new/additional columns.
How can this be done in AWS Athena? Currently this is how it looks like, but it complains `new_id` is not in source table (obviously).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "dst_orders"
WITH ( format='PARQUET', parquet_compression='SNAPPY', partitioned_by=ARRAY['new_id','year','month','day'], external_location = 's3://dev-bucket/api/dst/dst_orders/') AS
SELECT billing_address,
        totalprice,
        uuid,
        hour,
        new_id, <== This is the new column I need, also in 'partitioned_by'
        year,
        month,
        day
FROM "src_orders"
WITH NO DATA
```

Comment: Create the table first and then insert data into it.

Comment: exactly, thats why "WITH NO DATA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide both the column type and a name to the query.

Let's say that that the new field is an `int`.

Instead of specifying `new_id` (since it doesn't exist), use `0 as new_id`.

This will create a column called `new_id` of type `int`. Since you have specified `WITH NOT DATA`, the zero won't be stored -- it is simply being used to help identify the column type.